# error: Segmentation fault: 11 (in target 'proj' from project 'proj')

Tags: swift, xcode, tags, target, xcode11

I upgraded my Xcode to Xcode 11
and when I try to run it I got compiler error
I updated pod files but I still has the error

```
 for 'showFilter()' (at /Users/asma/Desktop/proj/subsidiary/proj/proj/InboxInteractor.swift:187:5)
0  swift                    0x0000000111036eb3 PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 51
1  swift                    0x0000000111036686 SignalHandler(int) + 358
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff72361b5d _sigtramp + 29
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib   0x00007fff72322cb7 tiny_malloc_from_free_list + 450
4  swift                    0x000000010cec512a swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitSILFunction(swift::SILFunction*) + 9866
5  swift                    0x000000010cd71700 swift::irgen::IRGenerator::emitGlobalTopLevel() + 1712
6  swift                    0x000000010ce9fa51 swift::performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::ModuleDecl*, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule> >, llvm::StringRef, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, llvm::LLVMContext&, llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, llvm::GlobalVariable**) + 1889
7  swift                    0x000000010cc8e521 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 36545
8  swift                    0x000000010cc81e54 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 6820
9  swift                    0x000000010cc0f3c3 main + 1219
10 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff721763d5 start + 1
error: Segmentation fault: 11 (in target 'proj' from project 'proj')
```